# How to attach custom element to shadow DOM in html web components in a secure way?

Tags: javascript, security, web-component, shadow-dom

In the new web components/custom elements, I want to attach it to a shadow DOM. However, I am not writing the custom element, someone else is. How can I ensure what they write will be put in a shadow DOM, or what they write, I can put in a shadow DOM, without them trying to do anything malicious first like destroy the main page?

Comment: actually it's the shadow DOM that may be attached to a custom element. you should clarify your question.

Comment: It's more about how to take code written by some one else who claims it's just a custom element class, and add that to your app, and then you attach a shadow Dom to it. But you find out their code has $('body').empty(). How do you check for that?

Comment: shadow dom can't do that

Comment: my question may still be unclear, but this is what i mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291529/how-to-prevent-malicious-use-of-web-components-shadow-dom

Comment: your question is clear and the answer is it's not possible

Comment: So if someone does a site that allows plugins to be made of web components from other people, they have to be manually checked?

Comment: Yes I guess, like for any Javascript Library.